# Hibernate select with AND condition and all AND in OR

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I want to do below with hibernate

select id from mytable where col1=? and col2=?
or col1=? and col2=?
or col1=? and col2=?
or col1=? and col2=? ...?

this condition or col1=? and col2=?  , can be in 1000s , is this possible to do hibernate without or condition

Comment: `select id from mytable where col1 in (...) and col2 in (...)` or use join to temporary table

Comment: this would give different result like i want 1,1 or 2,2 
but it would give 1,1 -- 1,2 ,, 2,2

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
SELECT id FROM mytable
WHERE (col1,col2) in (SELECT col1,col2 FROM mytable)
```

You can modify this depends on your specific values, like adding `WHERE` segment in the subquery or just list all your options.

can you be more specific about `col1,col2` values and how they appear in mytable (how strongly they are related to each other)?

Comment: I want to pass my values so would it be like 
SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE (col1,col2) in (? ,?)

and then query.setParamterList(lst1)
query.setParamterList(lst2)

Comment: this seems working only when in (query ) not with parameters , I need something with params and hibernate

Comment: are `col1,col2` numbers? strings?

Comment: Strings , but would that make any difference

Comment: not in the general case.  can you add some code? I think my solution works in the general case